# Add users from DisplayName list to security group

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I have the below user list and I want to add Active Directory users to the groups per this list. I know I cannot use `DisplayName` for adding members to groups, so how can I add the listed users to the groups?

Is there a good way to add users by converting `DisplayName` to `DN` or `SamAccountName`? Any advice and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
<Userlist.csv>
-----------
AddtoGroupname,DisplayName (*)
Group1,UserName1
Group1,UserName2
Group2,UserName3
...
```

(*) which are DisplayNames of member users which need to be add the left side group name.

Our environment is running Powershell 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by using `Get-ADUser` to get an AD User object based on filtering on DisplayName and then using `Add-ADGroupMember` to add them to the group.

Because Get-ADUser might return multiple results (if there are duplicate Display Names) this uses a ForEach to loop through any duplicates:

```
Import-CSV Userlist.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $Users = (Get-ADUser -filter "displayname -eq $($_.DisplayName)")
    ForEach ($User in $Users) {
        Write-Host "Adding $User to $($_.AddtoGroupName)"
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.AddtoGroupName -Members $User
    }
}
```

You might want to replace/remove the `Write-Host`, I just added it so you can see what is occurring.

Comment: Thank you Mark!! It's perfect!! I really appiciate your help!

Comment: Unfortunatly, It was not working when I tested... I have no idea why, but $Users return null..

Comment: Try changing the filter to: `"displayname -like $($_.DisplayName)"`

Comment: Oh it might also be that you need to request the displayname property. I'll amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. It's still not working... DisplayName has space it's like "User Name1" so it might be related the problem...

Comment: I've amended my answer to move the displayname filter into where-object. This will be a little less efficient but see if that helps. It might also be worth picking a few users and manually checking they have the expected display names.

Comment: I've also just added a Trim() on the display name in case there are any space characters around them in your CSV file that is tripping things up.

Comment: I really appriciate  for your kind help. I founded the cause and it was encoding of a csv file. I overwrited the csv in Unicode, then the below code which you showed me first worked!

Comment: Import-CSV Userlist.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $Name     = $_.displayname 
    $user = Get-aduser -Filter {displayname -eq $Name}
    ForEach ($User in $Users) {
        Write-Host "Adding $User to $($_.AddtoGroupName)"
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.AddtoGroupName -Members $User
    }
}

Comment: No problem, glad you found the issue. I've reverted the answer to it's original.